# Remote deployment of Docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

I'm not sure how to ask for that.

Basically, I've got some homemade Docker images that I don't want to share on a public registry.
Let's admit my company has 10 different customers. We have deployed 10 raspberries, one in each customer's facility.

What I'd like to do now, is to create a private marketplace where the customers will be able to select the packages they want to deploy on their raspberry and do a one-click deployment.

Does something like that exist?

I've taken a look at Kubernetes but it looks a bit too complicated for end-users. Is there a kind of abstraction dashboard or a way to do that by command line (that I would map to a web interface)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can still push your images to private repositories. Either in docker hub or other repositories like ECR, GCR. For deployment, only requirement is to have credentials of these repositories set in the respective deployment system.

Comment: Will that work for multiple clusters of a single machine ?

Comment: @Manitoba.I didn't get you. What do you mean by multiple clusters of a single machine?

Comment: I mean: one customer as one Kubernetes cluster. I'd like to be able to manage the machines with Kubernetes. If I'm not wrong, Kubernetes only deals with clusters.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter how many clusters. As long as you provide a image path to kubernetes deployment yaml. Under `containers.image:private.registry.com:my-shared-image:latest` will always pull same image on each cluster. Now you can use any private registry to host your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: private.registry.com:my-shared-image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

If don't specify full registry path , it will assume docker hub

securing you private repo and adding secret to kubernetes yaml is whole another topic

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Thanks. The solution would be to make the marketplace to deploy an image to the private registry. One registry for one customer. Right ?

Comment: Kubernetes itself will not help what you are trying to achieve. Docker registries will help you to host your images(each image having different versions),

Comment: I would rather create a web app to display list all available artifacts(packages that you mentioned). These packages will be stored somewhere and then can be downloaded by clients. Totally depends on what kinds of packages , which language, how they going to be installed on those raspberries